# Foundation Rails Styling - Looping Posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, zurb-foundation

**Goal**: Have 3 posts per `.row` on the Posts index page

How can I modify the below code so that a new `.row` is generated after the third post in the `@posts.each do |post|` loop?

`.container.posts-container
   @posts.each do |post|
     .row
       .medium-4.columns
         %h1
           = post.title`

The problem with the above code is that it creates a new row whenever a new post is created. I would like to modify it to have 3 posts per row. Thus, there needs to be 3 `.medium-4.columns` per row. How can this be done? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this to get 3 posts per row

```
@posts.each_slice(3) do |post_slices|
  .row
    - post_slices.each do |post|
      .medium-4.columns
        %h1
          = post.title
```